# The CasperJS's method "scrollTo" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm learning the CasperJS to fetch the images from other website which used ajax to load images , i read the api documentation from the CasperJS official website and find the method "scrollTo" , so i have been tried it to simulate the client behavior , and check the height of window

code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://github.com/qianjiahao',function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle())
}).then(function(){
    this.scrollTo(1500,768); 
}).then(function(){
    this.echo(document.documentElement.scrollHeight);   // 300
    this.echo(document.documentElement.scrollWidth);    // 400  
}).run();
```

then i find the other method to change the viewport and try it again

code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://github.com/qianjiahao',function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle())
}).viewport(1024, 768,function(){
    this.scrollTo(1500,768);
    this.echo(document.documentElement.scrollHeight);    // 300
    this.echo(document.documentElement.scrollWidth);     // 400
}).run();
```

but i got the same result as before , i'm confusing and if you can help i will be appreciate of you .

there is a website with a lot of images , i use CasperJS fetch the src of images , only if the src of images which i can see i can get the real src , the src of images which i can't see is fake , like this :

```
http://img.topitme.com/img/style/blank.gif
```

this is just a blank image . the image can load when i scroll the window and can see it , so i want to simulate the customer behavior and make the website load all image , in that case i can get all of image's src . so i use the method "scrollTo" and "viewport", but it doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't made clear what result you got and what result you expected.

Comment: @ArtjomB. there is a website with a lot of image , i use CasperJS fetch the src of images , only if the src of images which i can see i can get the real src , the src of images which i can't see is fake , like this :

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? Have you taken a screenshot and looked at the page? Also, `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` gives the height of the page and not the scroll offset if that is what you're thinking about. Since it is so small, either the page is not loaded or there is another element (not `<body>`) that scrolls, so scrollTo() probably won't work.